# History with flow router meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, flow-router

With iron router going back to previous page was as easy as
`history.back()`
how do I achieve the same with flow router

Comment: well... `history.back()` !
I use flow router and that works for me. this is a Javascript thing, not a router dependent thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the Flow router docs:

> Normally, all the route changes made via APIs like FlowRouter.go and
>   FlowRouter.setParams() add a URL item to the browser history.

So `history.back()` should work as expected.

if you use `FlowRouter.withReplaceState(fn)` then the history will not be recorded.
See: https://github.com/kadirahq/flow-router#flowrouterwithreplacestatefn
for more details

This is not the default thought.